# Getting Data Validation List from Data Model or a Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very specific question that I couldn't find the answer on anywhere.

I know how to make a dynamic validation list using named ranges like `=OFFSET(Source!$Q$2,0,0,COUNTA(Source!$Q:$Q)-1,1)`

My question is, can I make this dynamic validation list from a data model or query source without using actual sheet references? Currently I create a table query on a sheet, reference the column to a named range like above and hide the page so it doesn't appear on sheet list. But I even want to get rid of the need for a physical page so everything happens on background.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. The source for an Excel Data Validation List must be either a hard-coded list or else a reference to a range within an actual worksheet.